# Each row of a MySQL-database stored in an object via PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I try to get something like this from a MySQL-database via PHP and PDO query:

```
return array(
    "Jungle Book" => new Book("Jungle Book", "R. Kipling", "A classic book."),
    "Moonwalker" => new Book("Moonwalker", "J. Walker", ""),
    "PHP for Dummies" => new Book("PHP for Dummies", "Some Smart Guy", "")
);
```

Each row of the database should be stored in an object. 
Can anyone help me with this?

I tried this:

```
return array(
    foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM books") as $row) {
        $row['name'] => new Book($row['name'], $row['author'], $row['description']);
    }
)
```

...but foreach isn't allowed in arrays...

Background: for learning purposes I'm following this tutorial: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/ and I'm trying now to replace the static list of books with code that is working with a real database.

Comment: You need `$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM books")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` for it to work. Foreach IS made for arrays. You wanted to foreach an object (PDOStatement).

Comment: @N.B., you shouldn't chain the fetchAll() off of query(), because query() isn't guaranteed to return a PDOStatement object.  It returns `false` on error.

Comment: @BillKarwin - the person is in the learning process, throwing terms such as we are isn't helping for the time being. I know how to use the manual and sorry if I sound rude but I personally do know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with mvc or pdo actually, but rather with PHP syntax at all.

Your task is rather simple, only you need is to refrain from idea of having **all the code** in one single operator:

```
$data = array();
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM books");
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $data[$row['name']] = new Book($row['name'], $row['author'], $row['description']);
}
return $data;
```

Although PDO has a syntax sugar for you, in my opinion one have to learn the underlying basic statements first.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion and your code. The code works absolutely for me, when I'm replacing the double-arrow in line 4 with a simple assignment operator. (I can't edit it without changing more than 6 characters...). I think this was just a slip of the pen? Or am I doing something wrong?
You're right, I'm not that strong in PHP overall, and just trying to learn some oop, mvc and pdo concepts with working examples... maybe I have to go back to some PHP basics first.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the fetch type to FETCH_CLASS.

Creating and returning the array in a single statement is an artificial and needless requirement.  I wouldn't do that, it makes one's code hard to debug, hard to test, and hard to maintain.  Also the query() method may return `false` on error, so it will be a fatal error if you try to use it in a foreach statement.

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM books");
if ($stmt === false) { /* do something to handle the error */ }
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Book');
return $results;
```

Or if you want a results array indexed by name:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM books");
if ($stmt === false) { /* do something to handle the error */ }
$results = array();
while ($book = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Book')) {
  $results[$book->name] = $book;
}
return $results;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!
I think returning the array not via a single statement makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably wanting to return associative array values. In your current code, you cannot run a `foreach` while inside the array. But you can do this:

```
return $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM books")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```